# How to run WordPress and Java web app running on Tomcat on the same server?

Tags: redirects, apache, wordpress, tomcat, reverse-proxy

I have to run a WordPress site served via Apache2 & Java-based webapp using Tomcat on the same server.

When users come to `example.com` or `example.com/public-pages` they need to served from **WordPress** but when they come to `example.com/private-pages` they need to be served from the **Tomcat**.

I have asked [this question on serverfault](https://serverfault.com/questions/604099/howto-run-wordpress-site-along-with-tomcat-web-aplication-on-the-same-server/604128) where they suggested using different port, different IP & sub-domain.

I want to go for `different port` solution since it will mean I need to buy only one SSL certificate.

I tried doing the reverse proxy method by having the following in my `default-ssl.conf`

```
    <VirtualHost _default_:443>
            ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
            ServerName localhost:443

            DocumentRoot /var/www

            <Directory /var/www>
            #For Wordpress
                    Options FollowSymLinks
                    AllowOverride All
            </Directory>

            <Proxy *>
                    Order deny,allow
                    Allow from all
            </Proxy>

            ProxyRequests           Off
            ProxyPass               /private-pages       ajp://localhost:8009/
            ProxyPassReverse        /private-pages       ajp://localhost:8009/


            SSLEngine on
            SSLProxyEngine On


            SSLCertificateFile      /etc/apache2/ssl/apache.crt
            SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/apache.key

    </VirtualHost>
```

As you have noticed I am using `mod_proxy_ajp` in Apache2 for this. And that my Tomcat is listening to port `8009` and then serving content. So now when I go to `example.com/private-pages` I am seeing the content from my Tomcat. But 2 issues are happening.

1. All my static resources are getting 404-ed, so none of my images, CSS, js are getting loaded. I see that the browser is requesting for the resources using URL `example.com/css/*` This will clearly not work because it translates to `example.com:80/css/*` instead of `example.com:8009/css/*` & there are no such resources in the WordPress directory.
2. If I go to `example.com/private-pages/abcd` I am somehow kicked to the WordPress site (which obviously displays a 404 page).

I can understand why #1 is happening but have no clue why the #2 is happening. Regardless, if there is another clean solution for resolving this, I would appreciate y'alls help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to finally resolve the issue by doing couple of things.

1. Renamed the WAR file in my tomcat, in this case **private-pages**
2. In my virtual hosts definition I changed ajp:// to reflect the above change.

Here is virtual hosts file,

```
<VirtualHost _default_:443>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        ServerName localhost:443

        DocumentRoot /var/www

        <Directory /var/www>
        #For Wordpress
                Options FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride All
        </Directory>

        <Proxy *>
                Order deny,allow
                Allow from all
        </Proxy>

        ProxyPreserveHost On
        ProxyRequests           Off
        ProxyPass               /private-pages       ajp://localhost:8009/private-pages
        ProxyPassReverse        /private-pages       ajp://localhost:8009/private-pages

        <Location /private-pages>
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
        </Location>



        SSLEngine on
        SSLProxyEngine On


        SSLCertificateFile      /etc/apache2/ssl/apache.crt
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/apache.key

</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use mod_rewrite to specify which directory gets the reverse proxy.   Part of your problem is that the rewrite rules for WordPress are stealing requests from the proxy.   If you use mod_rewrite for the proxy, then you can specify `[L]` to indicate that the proxy rule is the *last* rewrite rule and that the WordPress rewrite rules shouldn't be used.

```
ProxyRequests off
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/private-pages  ajp://localhost:8009/  [P,L]
ProxyPassReverse /private-pages ajp://localhost:8009/
```

To solve your CSS problem, you could use [mod_proxy_html](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_proxy_html.html) which could be configured to rewrite all the HTML that comes back through the proxy and replace references to `/css/` with `/private-pages/css`.

Alternately, you could modify the web application that is running inside Tomcat7 to be proxy aware.  [mod_proxy can be configured to send `via:` headers](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxyvia).  [It also sends `x-forwarded` headers](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html#x-headers) that your web app could examine and know that it is running in a reverse proxy situation.